# How to iterate through Stripe collection JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe payments to return a list of invoices to my AngularJS app.

I get the following result:

```
Stripe\Collection JSON: {
"object": "list",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "in_1BKR1lK9EsaSH2dAtMQ4JF1K",
        "object": "invoice",
        "amount_due": 113,
        "application_fee": null,
        "attempt_count": 1,
        "attempted": true,
        "billing": "charge_automatically",
        "charge": "ch_1BKRxsK9EsaSH2dA0xW34Qsr",
        "closed": true,
        "currency": "gbp",
        "customer": "cus_9ry4RT082N7T7N",
        "date": 1509799533,
        "description": null,
        "discount": null,
        "ending_balance": 0,
        "forgiven": false,
        "lines": {
            "object": "list",
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "ii_1BJm2pK9EsaSH2dA6t4ytmm6",
                    "object": "line_item",
                    "amount": 6,
                    "currency": "gbp",
                    "description": "Remaining time on per act monthly after 02 Nov 2017",
```

... etc

How do I iterate through this JSON to list each invoice object?

I have tried:

```
$scope.myUserData.invoices = result.data; (returns above JSON) 
$scope.myUserData.invoices = result.data[0]; (returns "S")
$scope.myUserData.invoices = result.data.object; (returns blank)
$scope.myUserData.invoices = result.data.data; (returns blank)
```

Comment: `result.data.data`?

Comment: returns blank - added to question

Comment: what is typeof "result"? i can consider that it is a string. If yes, you need JSON.parse() to convert it to javascript json.

Comment: The object is string

Comment: Has the json been parsed? If not, call JSON.parse(result) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `result.data[0]` returns character 'S', your `result` object is most likely a string. So you might try using `JSON.parse()` like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(json.data[0]);
```

---

Edited: adapted by using OP's observations


your result object is stringify-ed somewhere on the way (and should be a json object in the first place), then using

```
$scope.myUserData.invoices = angular.fromJson(result.data);
```

should work.

Comment: doing that gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: well, in that case try parsing `result.substring(result.indexOf('{'))` but this looks more like a workaround since your `result` object is stringify-ed somewhere on the way (and should be a json object in the first place) - so maybe you should look that up in the first place

Comment: Right you are! The result was being called by an API which was sending the response straight back, but stringifying it without me realising. I made sure it returned JSON. Then the line $scope.myUserData.invoices = angular.fromJson(result.data); did the trick. Please make an answer so I can mark it. Thanks!

Comment: your result object is stringify-ed somewhere on the way (and should be a json object in the first place) + $scope.myUserData.invoices = angular.fromJson(result.data); is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will help

```js
let x = 'Stripe\Collection JSON: {hello:"world"}';//Should be your result instead this string
x = x.replace("Stripe\Collection JSON: ", "");
x = JSON.stringify(x)
x = JSON.parse(x);
console.log(x)
```

Just put your result value instead. Then you should have a JSON object, and do this result.data[0]

Answer (score -1):

Slight change to the answer Edward gave, the backslash needs to be escaped.

This allowed me to get the result in just Typescript, works in Angular too:

```
  let x = result._body;
  x = x.replace("Stripe\\Collection JSON: ", "");
  x = JSON.parse(x);

  x.data.forEach(element => {
    console.log('card JSON: ' + JSON.stringify(element));
    console.log('card id: ' + element.id);
  });
```